# What is the significance of 1st of October?

Tags: idioms, expressions, lyrics

In the song [Paper Planes](https://genius.com/Mia-paper-planes-blaqstarr-remix-lyrics), there's a passage as quoted below.

> My name is Olushola, I just got off my visa
>   I live everyday like it's the first of October

I wonder what the significance of the 1st of October is. What does it mean to *live like it's 1st of October* and where does that expression originate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among [many other things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_1), October 1 is [Nigeria's Independence Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(Nigeria)), marking Nigeria's independence from British colonial rule in 1960. This is a day of celebration, so "living every day like it's the 1st of October" suggests the speaker likes to party, or to treat each day as a celebration of life.

Another line from this remix of the song supports this:

> I'm fresh from Lagos, fresh from Nigeria

[Olushola](http://www.name-doctor.com/name-olushola-meaning-of-olushola-47962.html) is also a common male name in much of western Africa.

"Party like it's (time)" appears to have originated in [Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(musician))'s 1982 song [*1999*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_(Prince_song)) which contains the lyrics "party like it's 1999," referencing the massive turn-of-the-millennium celebrations anticipated at the time.

Comment: It is worth noting that, outside of the Nigerian community, the significance of the first of October isn't known, and so most native speakers of English would not recognise this reference.

Comment: Hahaha, OMG, I'm so dumb. I had guessed before asking here that it might be a reference to a national holiday so I got [3rd of August as the Day of Independence](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNSvCSFJoxLObHd1npbPtc5j7ae31g:1573932615483&q=When+did+Niger+become+independent%3F&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyzsjzu-_lAhWt-ioKHYu1D5AQzmd6BAguEBA&biw=1920&bih=966). It's correct for **Niger** and I thought the guy sang *fresh from Niger, yeah*. Now that I read the lyrics properly again (and have read your answer), it's so obvious...